# Livestream link MediaPlayer Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get this stream to play:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.setDataSource("http://knhc-ice.streamguys1.com/live");
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when the application runs it is giving me this error:

```
2019-03-17 17:01:05.035 5924-5924/com.example.android.c895 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

I understand that the link that I am passing into the media player is just a single player, but I want that player to automatically play and be passed to the MediaPlayer. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was able to figure out was put my MediaPlayer on Async Task(background thread) on my application.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        b = (ImageButton) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        new PlayerTask().execute(s);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(started)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        }); 
class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {


        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Since the codes are almost identically the same, could anyone answer why this works and not just on the main thread?